# Creating nested XML element output from flat XML data using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am having difficulty creating nested XML elements from a flat XML data source.  The goal is to take the `<Path>`, where each level is represented in the hierarchy by listing of each `<Level>`, and convert that to a **nested** `<Folder>` hierarchy in output XML file.

The source dataset XML file looks like this:

```
<Path>
  <Level DataID='2000' Name='Root'></Level>
  <Level DataID='427438' Name=Sub Level 1'></Level>
  <Level DataID='427439' Name=Sub Level 2'></Level>
  <Level DataID='427440' Name=Sub Level 3'></Level>
</Path>
```

The desired output is nested `<folder>` elements, where the number of nested elements could vary based on the number of `<levels>` in the dataset.

```
<Parent>
<folder displayName="Root">
  <folder displayName="Level 1">
    <folder displayName="Level 2">
      <folder displayName="Level 3">
      </folder>
    </folder>
  </folder>
</folder>
</Parent>
```

I've been trying various approaches with the `<xsl:apply-templates>` and `<xsl:for-each>` tags, where the output uses `<xsl:element>` tag, but to no avail.

Comment: Your source XML is invalid. Not all attributes are proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to create a nested structure from a flat input is the one below. Unfortunately your input XML is invalid(see my comment above), so the output does not necessarily match your full requirements(There is a "Sub " in front of your "Level" 's):

This XSLT should do the trick by recursively applying `xsl:call-template`:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    <xsl:template match="Path">
      <Parent>
        <xsl:call-template name="SubFolder">
          <xsl:with-param name="curElem" select="Level[1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </Parent>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="SubFolder">
      <xsl:param name="curElem" />
      <folder displayName="{$curElem/@Name}">
        <xsl:if test="$curElem/following-sibling::Level[1]">
          <xsl:call-template name="SubFolder">
            <xsl:with-param name="curElem" select="$curElem/following-sibling::Level[1]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </folder>      
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output (applied to a sanitized input XML) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent>
    <folder displayName="Root">
        <folder displayName="Sub Level 1">
            <folder displayName="Sub Level 2">
                <folder displayName="Sub Level 3"/>
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</Parent>
```

There may be easier solutions, but it does the job.